# click() command not working on document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scripting

Im making automated browser scripts with javascript and I want to use the click() command on this website but the button on the website doesnt have an Id (which works fine). However it only has a class name. When I do `document.getElementsByClassName(btn.btn-danger.btn-lg.btn-block.betButton).click()` it doesnt work.

Here is the inspect of the button I want to click:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-color="r">1 to 7, Win x2</button>
```

Is it possible to use the click() function on the button? Is there someway to assign an Id myself? Thanks for any answers :)

I dont think that is a copy as I know what differences are. But the button doesnt have any Id only a class name. And as that doesnt work what else could I do to trigger a click() event?

Edit2 = There is 3 buttons with all the same class names the only difference is the text of the button and the data-color, is there any way to manipulate that?

Comment: That method returns a collection of elements, not just a single one.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: You can't put `.` between the classes in `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: @Barmar that doesnt work...

Comment: @SamZi It will if you put a `.` before the first class name, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is an array-like object.

That means that in you case, you should get the element at index 0, which ideally for the kind of application that you are building should be the only one that you get:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block betButton')[0].click()
```

Otherwise your extension will probably stop working if the websites gets updated and the elements that matches your selector change order.

Note also that as @Barmar pointed out, to filter by multiple classes with `getElementsByClassName` you should use spaces, not dots.

Let's say you have:

```
<button class="a"></button>
<button class="a b"></button>
<button class="a.b"></button>
```

Then:

- `document.getElementsByClassName('a')` will return a `HTMLCollection` with all the elements with class `a`: `[<button class="a"></button>, <button class="a b"></button>]`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('a b')` will return a `HTMLCollection` with all the elements with classes `a` and `b`: `[<button class="a b"></button>]`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('a.b')` will return a `HTMLCollection` with all the elements with class `a.b`: `[<button class="a.b"></button>]`

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to be able to use selectors like `.a.b` or just [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which instead of a `HTMLCollection` will return just the first element that matches the selector, so you can call `click` on it straight away:

```
document.querySelector('.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg.btn-block.betButton').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `.`'s
2. The function returns an array-like object, a hint is in the name as it is plural so you have to specify a key in the array.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-color="r">1 to 7, Win x2</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cra73ywn/)

### Note...

As can be seen in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cra73ywn/1/), you *need* to remove the `.` for it work, as JavaScript already knows you are selecting classes through the function you are using.

**Using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector('.btn-danger.btn-lg.btn-block.betButton').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cra73ywn/2/)