# How to trigger a click on an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following Html:

```
<div class="box-row">
    <div class="box c2-3">
        <div class="box-overlay"></div>
        <div class="box-letter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box c2-4">
        <div class="box-overlay"></div>
        <div class="box-letter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box c2-5">
         <div class="box-overlay"></div>
         <div class="box-letter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box c2-6 trr">
         <div class="box-overlay trr"></div>
         <div class="box-letter"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to randomly select one of the elements with class: c2-3, c2-4, c2-5, c2-6 and trigger a click.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
    var map = [
        'c2-3', 'c2-4', 'c2-5', 'c2-6',
    ];

    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName(map[x]);
```

At this point I want to trigger the click and am unsure how to do it:

```
 element.trigger('click'); ??
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` - note the `s` in element**s**. This method returns a *collection* of elements. You cannot call `.trigger()` or `.click()` on a collection; you must first target a specific element in the collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [click() command not working on document.getElementsByClassName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059088/click-command-not-working-on-document-getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: Ah, and since it is a class I am looking for, there could be multiple classes...

Comment: @TylerRoper That thread actually solved my problem. I changed getElementsByClassName with querySelector and it now works. Thanks!

Comment: querySelector/querySelectorAll is easier (and fun fact, has better browser support)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`element.click();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) instead of `element.trigger('click');` but also, you need to either get only a single element, or loop over the returned [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) from [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName).

For example, to loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(map[x])
elements.forEach(element => element.click())
```

...Or, to get a single element (still using `getElementsByClassName`):

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(map[x])[0]
element.click()
```

Alternatively, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var element = document.querySelector(`.${map[x]}`)
element.click()
```

Comment: Tried it, I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: element.click is not a function"

Comment: So, the JS you provided is actually the entirety of your JS code?

Comment: It is watered down a bit for brevity.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, I assumed you were getting a single element in a hidden step, at first.